# Do I have to verify google tokenID on every request?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-signin

I am implementing a sign in with google feature for a website. I have managed to log the user in with the Google Javascript API. It it stated by google that once we get the tokenID, we have to verify it in the backend server, in order to verify that the current signed in user is valid.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

I have managed to implement the server side verification, the doubt that I have is that do I have to verify the tokenID in the back end for every request by user ?, or should I validate it for every action by the user ?or is there an another approach to this ?

Can some one point me in the correct path ?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just implement the listeners ? Like mentioned here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners .

Comment: Ok so if i implement this does that mean I dont have to verify it on the server side?. I once saw that I have to verify this on server side to prevent malicious attacker from making requests ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the server creates sessions, you don't need to send or verify id_token. If you do need sessions, do send id_token to server and verify. For example, when you want to personalize a user and save his/her data on a server, please send and verify id_token.

Verifying id_token is needed only once when the session is created. id_token is a proof that Google has authenticated the user which you can trust as long as properly verified. Once session expires, you should verify id_token again since id_token has expiration date/time.